# How to add a new folder from the disk, into an Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse

On searching, all I get are results for how to import an existing project into Eclipse. My problem is different.

I have a war file which I imported to Eclipse. Now I want to add nvd3's files to the project, and have placed [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/)'s folder in the `WebContent/scripts/lib` folder on the disk. Now there seems to be no way to make Eclipse recognize that the `nvd3` folder exists there. There seems to be no way to add it either in Eclipse. Using the JavaEE version of Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: Just refresh it and try to clean the project...

Comment: Refresh worked. Thanks. Please post this as an answer and I'll select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these common steps...

1) Select root directory of the project

2) Right click on it.

3) Click on Refresh

There you go.... :)